# How to disable Emacs messages like "You can run the command X with Y"

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

When I run a command that prompts for input in the minibuffer, it's annoying to have the text overwritten by supposedly helpful messages like:

```
You can run the command 'package-list-packages' with <menu bar> <options> <packages>
```

Is there a way to disable these specifically for menu bar suggestions, which I never use?  If not, how can I disable them globally?

Comment: Those messages should not occur for menu-bar bindings.  And indeed for me `M-x package-list-packages RET` does not give me the message you show.  So it looks like a bug that's triggered by something in your .emacs.  Please figure out which part of your .emacs triggers it and then `M-x report-emacs-bug` so we can fix it.

Comment: @Stefan After some experimentation, it looks like that particular instance was caused by using the 'smex' package, not vanilla Emacs.  It can be disabled within smex rather easily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set variable `suggest-key-bindings` to `nil`.

```
(setq suggest-key-bindings nil)
```

Comment: or set it to a number < 2 to reduce the amount of time for which the message is visible (and despite the customize interface validation, this can be a value between 0 and 1)